# Nginx proxying Ghost blog and Node App unable to find assets

Tags: node.js, nginx, ghost-blog, ghost

I've been trying to host my website (a Node app) and my Ghost blog on the same Digital Ocean droplet. I've got Nginx all set up so that requests to '/' are sent to port 8080 where my site is being served and requests at '/blog' are sent to 2368, Ghost's default port number.

The problem is that the Ghost installation doesn't seem to be able to find the assets folder in its directory. The base HTML content shows up, but devoid of styling. I've tried configuring the root to point to the subdirectory Ghost resides in to no avail.

This is an error I'm getting (404s throughout):

GET http://MYURL/assets/css/screen.css?v=59384a3875 
MYURL/:126 
 404 (Not Found)

[Picture: HTML content appears, but no styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j76U.png)

Nginx Config:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name MYURL;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Ghost Production Config:

```
var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {
    // ### Production
    // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment.
    // Configure your URL and mail settings here
    production: {
        url: 'http://MYURL',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
 },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2368'
        }
    },
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `/assets/css/screen.css?v=59384a3875` which is not proxied I mean you did not yet added  `location /assets` but still using. You need to add another `location` directive for `assets` like your nginx config would be

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name MYURL;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /assets {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /blog {
        rewrite ^/blog(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

#### another solution

You may like to remove `/` from all static content like use `assets/css/screen.css?v=59384a3875`  rather than `/assets/css/screen.css?v=59384a3875` but you have remove from everywhere in html, js, css, etc.

Comment: that `rewrite...` line above was the life saver after 2+ hours googling this issue - well done